# ¿Cómo guardar los datos de este array en una tabla pivote?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un formulario con 4 campos + 1 oculto, y tengo la opción de agregar otro grupo más de 4 `inputs` para agregar a otra persona (Cada vez que presiono el botón agregar, me agrega un grupo más de 4 `inputs`, puedo agregar varias personas.

Cada grupo de 4 campos pertenece a una persona (`first_name`, `last_name`, `dni`, `phone`, y `code` que es el quinto, es el mismo para todos).

Ahora no sé como puedo obtener la data para guardar a cada persona en una tabla pivote, ya que se guarda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi controlador guardo todos los campos de la siguiente forma cuando es un solo registro:

```
$info = Info::create($request->all());
```

Pero no sé como implementar el foreach allí para guardar como registros independientes cada persona en la tabla pivote.

Controlador actualizado, obviamente no funciona:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->all()) {
        Visit::create([
            'code' => $request->code,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'dni' => $request->dni,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
        ]);
    }

    return view('web.completed');
}
```

Blade:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'info.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form']) !!}

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        {{ Form::label('first_name', 'Nombre') }}
        {{ Form::text('first_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        {{ Form::label('last_name', 'Apellido') }}
        {{ Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        {{ Form::label('dni', 'DNI') }}
        {{ Form::text('dni', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-left">
        {{ Form::label('phone', 'Teléfono') }}
        {{ Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group text-left">
    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-block']) }}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: una duda los guardas pero necesitas borrarlos y editarlos ?

Comment: No, necesito guardalos pero no sé como

Comment: agrega el el `blade` de como lo estas llenando y luego enviando y tambien el controlador de como lo estas intentando obtener si solo es una linea no importa.

Comment: yo hice algo similar pero yo no uso modelos pero me funciona.

Comment: Buenos días, ya lo actualicé con un cambio en el controlador pero ya verás porque no me funciona.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta